# Make internal Disk bootable in MacBook Pro

Tags: hard-drive, boot, mac

I have installed new NVMe hard drive on my MacBook because the old one has been corrected.

The new hard drive is shown up at Disk Utility as normal.

I had formatted it as Mac OS Extended and the schema as GUID.

I started to install OS, it asked me where i want to install... I selected the hard drive and it started copying but after restarting... the Mac boot from the same USB driver and re-enter to the Disk Utility.

I checked info about the disk
it is show that my internal new hard drive as non bootable.
How I can change that? how I can make the Mac boot from the new hard drive?

[image]

[image]

It is MacBook Pro Retina Late 2013

Comment: https://support.apple.com/pt-pt/guide/security/sec7703b1423/web

Comment: Precisely what Mac is it & what OS was on it last? 6GB used space doesn't seem enough for an OS installation. I'd expect something more like 15 - 18GB for a virgin High Sierra [I'm assuming that's what I can not quite see under the info window.]. Are you certain you installed to the right place? Are you certain you formatted GUID? Press Cmd/2 to be able to see the device view - you're currently only showing the volume view.

Comment: MacBook Pro A1398. Yes I installed it on the 500 GB hard drive.

Comment: Sorry, you can't identify a Mac from the 'A' number - they re-use those numbers. There are 21 different Macs with that code, from 2012 to 2015. You can get the model designation from About This Mac in the  menu. But OK, we have a GUID/HFS+ drive, but 6GB still isn't enough for a complete OS install - it's about the size of an installer [HS is about 5.3GB], but not an installed OS. (You still need to answer my other earlier questions too.)

Comment: I don't know exactly what is the OS was on it. Yes I formatted GUID, I bought a nvme and an adapter to place it on the board